# Javascript DOM make a table

Tags: javascript

Excuse the question.
I want to make a todo list like this.

https://gyazo.com/0dd4feeea3f7a27aefe6d2160944c65e

However, when I press the "Add button", the task goes to the right instead of going down.

In such cases, how should I implement it?

※As a condition, I want to separate addTask function and addButton function.

```js
    
    {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const addTaskTrigger = document.getElementsByClassName('addTask-trigger')[0];
    const addTaskTarget = document.getElementsByClassName('addTask-target')[0];
    const addTaskValue = document.getElementsByClassName('addTask-value')[0];
    let nextId = 0;
    const todos = [];
    
    var tableItem = document.createElement('tr');


    const addTask = (task, id) => {    
    let idSpanTd = document.createElement('td');
    let taskSpanTd = document.createElement('td');
      //要素内のHTML文章を変更する
      idSpanTd.innerText = id;
      taskSpanTd.innerText = task;
      //生成したテーブル要素をブラウザに表示する
      tableItem.append(idSpanTd);
      tableItem.append(taskSpanTd);
      addTaskTarget.append(tableItem);
      return(task,id)
    };
    
   //Button要素を生成する
   let removeButton = document.createElement('button');
   let createButton = document.createElement('button');

    const addButton = (button) => {

      let createButtonTd = document.createElement('td');
      let removeButtonTd = document.createElement('td');
      //要素内のHTML文章を変更する
      createButton.innerText = '作業中';
      removeButton.innerText = '削除';
      //生成したテーブル要素をブラウザに表示する
      tableItem.append(createButtonTd);
      tableItem.append(removeButtonTd);
      addTaskTarget.append(tableItem);
       //生成したbutton要素を生成する
       createButtonTd.append(createButton);
       removeButtonTd.append(removeButton); 
       return(button)
      };
  
      //追加ボタンをクリックした際にタスクを追加する処理を行う
    addTaskTrigger.addEventListener('click', () => {
       const task = addTaskValue.value;
       addTask(task, nextId++);
       addButton();
       addTaskValue.value = '';
      });
    
    //チェックリスト用オブジェクト
    const todo = {
       task: 'taskSpanTd',
       status: '作業中'
      };
    todos.push(todo);
    
    removeButton.addEventListener('click', delete_element, false);

    // //削除ボタンを押した時にタスクを削除する
    function delete_element () {
      let tabletag = this.closest ('tr');
      if (tabletag)
      tabletag.remove ();
    }
  
    });
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel ="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Todoリスト</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Todoリスト</h1>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="1" checked="checked">全て
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="2">作業中
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="3">完了
    </p>
<p></p>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>コメント</th>
        <th>状態</th>
        <th></th>
      </thead>
      <tbody class ="addTask-target"></tbody>
    </table>
    <h2>新規タスクの追加</h2>
    <input class="addTask-value" type="text" />
    <button class="addTask-trigger" type="button">追加</button>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined only one tableItem, only one removeButton and only one createButton.

You must define tableItem, removeButton and createButton as void variables, and only give them a value inside the `addTaskTrigger.addEventListener('click')` function. It would look like this:

```
 addTaskTrigger.addEventListener('click', () => {
     const task = addTaskValue.value;

     // Must be already defined as variables
     tableItem = document.createElement('tr');
     removeButton = document.createElement('button');
     createButton = document.createElement('button');

     addTask(task, nextId++);
     addButton();
     addTaskValue.value = '';
 });
```

You are defining only one event listener for each button (remove and create), but won't be enough for javascript to understand that it must listen to all of the rows' buttons. To do it the way you want, you must also define the eventListener only when the user adds a new task (you could define it inside the `addButton()` function, using the buttons IDs)

Answer (score 0):

Just move creating elements (`tableItem`, `removeButton`, `createButton`, etc.) to the `click` handler.

```js
 {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const addTaskTrigger = document.getElementsByClassName('addTask-trigger')[0];
    const addTaskTarget = document.getElementsByClassName('addTask-target')[0];
    const addTaskValue = document.getElementsByClassName('addTask-value')[0];
    let nextId = 0;
    const todos = [];


    const addTask = (task, id, tableItem) => {    
    let idSpanTd = document.createElement('td');
    let taskSpanTd = document.createElement('td');
      //要素内のHTML文章を変更する
      idSpanTd.innerText = id;
      taskSpanTd.innerText = task;
      //生成したテーブル要素をブラウザに表示する
      tableItem.append(idSpanTd);
      tableItem.append(taskSpanTd);
      addTaskTarget.append(tableItem);
      return(task,id)
    };
    
   //Button要素を生成する
    const addButton = (tableItem, removeButton, createButton) => {

      let createButtonTd = document.createElement('td');
      let removeButtonTd = document.createElement('td');
      //要素内のHTML文章を変更する
      createButton.innerText = '作業中';
      removeButton.innerText = '削除';
      //生成したテーブル要素をブラウザに表示する
      tableItem.append(createButtonTd);
      tableItem.append(removeButtonTd);
      addTaskTarget.append(tableItem);
       //生成したbutton要素を生成する
       createButtonTd.append(createButton);
       removeButtonTd.append(removeButton); 
      };
  
      //追加ボタンをクリックした際にタスクを追加する処理を行う
    addTaskTrigger.addEventListener('click', () => {
       const task = addTaskValue.value;
       const tableItem = document.createElement('tr');
         const removeButton = document.createElement('button');
       const createButton = document.createElement('button');
     
       addTask(task, nextId++, tableItem);
       addButton(tableItem, removeButton, createButton);
       addTaskValue.value = '';
       
       removeButton.addEventListener('click', delete_element, false);
      });
    
    //チェックリスト用オブジェクト
    const todo = {
       task: 'taskSpanTd',
       status: '作業中'
      };
    todos.push(todo);

    // //削除ボタンを押した時にタスクを削除する
    function delete_element () {
      let tabletag = this.closest ('tr');
      if (tabletag)
      tabletag.remove ();
    }
  
    });
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel ="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Todoリスト</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Todoリスト</h1>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="1" checked="checked">全て
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="2">作業中
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="3">完了
    </p>
<p></p>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>コメント</th>
        <th>状態</th>
        <th></th>
      </thead>
      <tbody class ="addTask-target"></tbody>
    </table>
    <h2>新規タスクの追加</h2>
    <input class="addTask-value" type="text" />
    <button class="addTask-trigger" type="button">追加</button>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</script>
</html>
```